# webscraping with webbot returns the wrong thing

Tags: python, web-scraping, webbot

I have this simple html code:

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <span class="bold-title">This is</span>
      " a test"
    </p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

i want to get " a test" by it's xpath using webbot

the code that seems to "work" is:

```py
from webbot import Browser
driver = Browser(showWindow=True)
driver.go_to('file:///C:/Users/myself/Desktop/test.html')
outp = driver.execute_script("return document.evaluate('/html/body/p/text()', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;")
print(outp)
```

the xpath "/html/body/p/text()" should theoretically return " a test", but webbot decided to print "[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]", what is going on?

Comment: what do you mean by webbot?

Comment: Webbot is  a library for python for web browser automation

https://pypi.org/project/webbot/